# Are there any terminal emulators written in Java?

Tags: linux, terminal, java, emulator

I'm looking for a terminal emulator that does the same thing as `gnome-terminal` or `konsole`, except written in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search turns up [Terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/).

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Java Telenet](http://www.mudconnect.com/java/Telnet/) - a terminal emulator that can be embedded in a web page and thus constitutes a zero-install application (assuming a JVM is available)

Google finds many, including [JTA](http://javassh.org/space/start) a Telnet and SSH client

Comment: Java Telenet is a broken link, a shame, it looks cool

Answer (score 0):

[JediTerm](https://github.com/traff/jediterm) is VT100 compatible and has implementations to work both for ssh connections and local pty.